# When using python `subprocess`, how can I use process number in arguments?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

Currently, I am running several scripts in parallel using `subprocess` as follows. `max_proc` seems to control how many processors I want. The below is the minimal code.

```
import os
import subprocess

def main():
    args = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    max_proc = 4
    processes = set()
    for arg in args:
        cmd = ['python', '-i', arg]
        processes.add(subprocess.Popen(cmd))
        if len(processes) >= max_proc:
            os.wait()
            processes.difference_update(
                [p for p in processes if p.poll() is not None])

    # Check if all the child processes were closed
    for p in processes:
        if p.poll() is None:
            p.wait()

main()
```

Running above will be something like:

```
# python -i a
# python -i b
# .. and so on
```

Here, if I want to include `process-number` (maybe from 1 to `max_proc`) in the argument, how can I modify this code? For example

```
# python -i a1
# python -i b2
# python -i c3
# python -i d4
# python -i e2
# python -i f1
# python -i h3
# python -i g4
# .. and so on
```

For this, I have to track which `process-number` is assigned and finished (and therefore ready to be reassigned). Is there a simple way?

*In short, I want at most 4 processes running in parallel. I also need to include the `process-number` (1~4, or 0~3 if zero-based) in the argument. Could you please help? *

Comment: Personally, I'd have one thread that loops on the number-1 processes (starting them in order), another that loops on the number-2 processes, etc. That way, for each thread it's a trivial linear operation. If you want to pull the work to do from a single pool, having a shared [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) isn't exactly tricky.

Comment: (also, "process-id" has an operating-system-level meaning, which it doesn't *look* like you intend here; clarifying would be helpful).

Comment: Thanks, Charles. (1) I didn't mean the OS-level real process ID, so I changed it. (2) You mean to initially divide whole arguments into 4 groups and run each group with the above code? That's good. However, I have no idea how long it will take for each argument. So initial division would bring serious imbalance in computation time. Does it make sense?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting any initial division at all. I'm suggesting each thread pull from a shared queue as it goes, so as soon as your (a given thread's) current process completes, it pops another off the queue and starts it.

Comment: I got it. Earlier I only saw the first version of your answer. It makes sense. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one actual thread for each parallel process, then that thread can consider the number it's assigned as part of its state, and just keep pulling input items off your shared queue and processing them in order.

As an example (replace `echo` with your real program):

```
import os, subprocess, threading

program_to_call = 'echo' ## change this

def run(items, num):
    try:
        while True:
            item = items.pop()
            subprocess.call([program_to_call, str(num), str(item)])
    except IndexError:
        return  ## "items" is empty

def main():
    queue = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
    max_proc = 4
    threads = []

    # start all four threads, passing each a different "num" and a reference to the queue
    for num in range(max_proc):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(queue, num))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    # wait for all four threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```